# Getting local time in PHP given a ISO 8601 datetime and timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, iso8601

I'm trying to get a local time given an ISO 8601 formatted datetime string in Zulu time, and a timezone string. I read the PHP documentation about the DateTime object and DateTimeZone, and I have tried a lot of stuff, but I cannot seem to get the right local time. What I have right now:

```
$datetime = '2017-05-29T10:30:00Z'; // I'm getting this value from an API call
$timezone = 'Europe/Prague'; // I'm getting this value from an API call
$date = new \DateTime( $datetime, new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) );
var_dump( $date->format('H:i') );
// I would expect it to be 12:30 since 29th May for this timezone would be GMT+2, but I get 10:30
```

So it's obvious I'm missing something about the DateTime and DateTimeZone classes, but I cannot get it right. Can anyone be so kind of helping me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got it right, for anyone interested:

```
$datetime = '2017-05-29T10:30:00Z'; // I'm getting this value from an API call
$timezone = 'Europe/Prague'; // I'm getting this value from an API call
$date = new \DateTime( $datetime, new \DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ); // as the original datetime string is in Zulu time, I need to set the datetimezone as UTC when creating
$date->setTimezone( new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) ); // this is what actually sets which timezone is printed in the next line
var_dump( $date->format('H:i') ); // yay! now it prints 12:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Prague");
echo date('H:i');
```

it will print date & time in 24 hours format.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` works for printing the current time (`date('H:i')`) in that timezone, but the results of `$date->format('H:i')` are not modified by this.

Comment: This worked for me: `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Prague");
$datetime = date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('H:i:s').'Z';
$timezone = 'Europe/Prague';
$date = new \DateTime( $datetime, new \DateTimeZone( $timezone ) );
var_dump( $date->format('H:i') );`

Comment: You are trying a static variable `$datetime = '2017-05-29T10:30:00Z';`.The time is 10:30 in the var so, your code is printing 10:30

Comment: I am getting this from an API call, so I cannot change it. I have updated the question to reflect this. As I stated in my original question, I'm trying to get the local time from a given ISO 8601 string + timezone, so your solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion lies in what timezone YOU are in as opposed to what timezone the datetime string is in. I'm in New Orleans, so my timezone is 'America/Chicago'. I would set that with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

Then, set the timezone of where your datetime string is coming FROM (I'll assume, Europe/Prague):

```
$datetimePrague = '2017-05-29T10:30:00Z';
$timezonePrague = 'Europe/Prague';
```

Now, when you create a DateTime object, pass it the datetime and timezone of where the time is coming FROM.

```
$datePrague = new \DateTime( $datetimePrague, new \DateTimeZone( $timezonePrague ) );
```

Then, get the timestamp of the DateTime object:

```
$timestamp = $datePrague->getTimestamp();
```

Finally, pass that timestamp to the date() function, along with your desired format, and you will have the equivalent of the DateTime in whatever timezone you're in:

```
date('H:i', $timestamp);
```

Here is the complete code, assuming I live in New Orleans, and I want to know what the local New Orleans time is for Prague time of 10:30:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$datetimePrague = '2017-05-29T10:30:00Z';
$timezonePrague = 'Europe/Prague';
$datePrague = new \DateTime( $datetimePrague, new \DateTimeZone( $timezonePrague ) );
$timestamp = $datePrague->getTimestamp();
var_dump(date('H:i', $timestamp));
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I actually wanted to get the local time: not my own time, but the time according to the timezone defined in `$timezone`, as the original datetime string is in Zulu time (that is UTC, so it is not in local time -> this is the Z in the ISO 8601 date format). So although your answer is very claryfing and helpful it didn't help me with my particular problem. I finally found out how to solve it and wrote an answer. Nonetheless I'm upvoting your answer for being so detailed and helpful :)

Comment: Well it seems I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to count but I gave it anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I think I was confused. I figured that Europe/Prague was where your datetime string was coming from. Glad you got it figured out!